# Use SQL statements in WinDev Mobile 21

Tags: android, sqlite, windev

I'm developing an Android app with a SQLite database in WM21 but I can't find the way to execute SQL statements like `ALTER TABLE`.

Query editor don't suport this kind of statements, function `HExecuteSQLQuery()` declares this query to the HFSQL engine and fails, and `SQLExec()` doesn't work because `SQLConnect()` isn't avaliable in Android.

Exists any way to do this with WM21?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to declare you table with the HDeclareExternal function and execute SQLExec on it ?

http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3044204&name=hdeclareexternal_function

Comment: It throw an error with code 73001: `In Java, HDeclareExternal is allowed on the HFSQL Classic or HFSQL Client/Server data files only.`